# Exportar archivo con filtros

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6, laravel-excel

tengo el siguiente código que me genera un fichero excel y me lo descarga funciona a excepción que no me pone el primer row como filtro.

La llamada la hago desdel controlador de esta forma

```
/**
 * @param $fecha_ini
 * @param $fecha_fin
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse
 */
public function exportExcelFile($fecha_ini , $fecha_fin)
{

    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();

    return Excel::download( new EncuestasExport($fecha_ini, $fecha_fin), 'encuestas.xls');

}
```

El fichero de exportación tiene esta estructura

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Encuesta;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;

class EncuestasExport implements FromQuery , WithHeadings , WithMapping, WithEvents
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct(string $fechaInicio, string $fechaFin)
    {
        $this->fechaInicio = $fechaInicio;
        $this->fechaFin = $fechaFin;

    }

    public function query()
    {
        return Encuesta::query()
            ->where('fecha','>=',$this->fechaInicio);
    }


    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'ID',
            'Tipo',
            'Nombre'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $row
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function map($row): array
    {
        $fecha = Carbon::parse($row->fecha)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');

        return [
            $row->id,
            $row->tipo,
            $row->nombre,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function registerEvents(): array
    {

        return array(
            AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                $event->sheet->setAutoFilter();
            }
        );
    }

}
```

El método que no me esta funcionando es el último "registerEvents" , lo que le digo es que en la hoja me active el auto-filtro pero no me lo hace.

También he probado con este código

```
$event->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('A1:P1');
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación he encontrado esto que te añadirá el filtro en todas las columnas del excel.

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter(
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
        ->calculateWorksheetDimension()
);
```

Te dejo el link de la documentación que te permite hacer filtros mas customizados espero que te sea de ayuda

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/autofilters/